# Regular Expression to extract string with in brackets

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the below string

```
 [2]  This is a test 1 <cr><lf>

 [3] This is a Test2   <cr><lf>

 [6] all  test5     <cr><lf>
 .

 .
 .
```

I am already reading the above in a loop so that I can read one line at a time

```
   For Each parsedNewLine As String In ParseFileFooter.Split(New String()     {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I want to extract 2 and This is a test1, 3 and This is a Test2 and 6 This is a test5 in an array or list or any other collection
I want to loop through the collection and insert 2 as one column of the database and this is a test 1 as another column of the database.
so basically I want this

```
col1     col2
 2        this is a test 1
 3        this is a test2
 6        all test5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex Fiddle: http://regex101.com/r/pB1yX5/1

```
/^.*(\[\d+\])\W(.*)$/gmi
```

Comment: ps. top right panel on the link will give you a color coded explanation of the regex.  For info on how to use this within VB.Net, see http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet